# Javascript - How to select multiple files and load into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a button select for 4 files and load "One" into a div. 
For example if I where to click on a video icon. Only load video.php into a div container. If I where to next click on music.php replace the current video.php loaded file with the new music.php video file (This is to toggle feed contents) such as music, pictures, videos, status's etc.
 I currently have this script:

Note: It works, however loads each file on top of each other. Rather than one at a time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#music").click(function() {
    $("#fload").load('music.php');
  });
  $("#video").click(function() {
    $("#fload").load('video.php');
  });
  $("#status").click(function() {
    $("#fload").load('status.php');
  });
  $("#picture").click(function() {
    $("#fload").load('picture.php');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="row Feed_Toggle_Row">
  <a href="#" id="video">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> 
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="music">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> 
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="status">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> 
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="picture">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> 
    </div>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="feedloadfull" id="fload"></div>
```

Comment: First of all, just wrap all your click listeners into one `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: You can use [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove from the container before loading.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Updated

Comment: Use .append()? http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @CassieJRound do you mean all the files are loading at the same time when you click a button, or do you just mean that old files are still visible in `#fload` after you click a new button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, you can use `.empty()` to clear the container. You can really shorten this up and make it more efficient:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Feed_Toggle_Row').on('click', 'a', function(){ // handles all of the links within the class
        var whatWasClicked = this.id; // returns music, status, etc.
        var toLoad = whatWasClicked + '.php'; // create the name of the file
        $('#fload').empty(); // clear the div
        $('#fload').load(toLoad); // load it back up again
    });
});
```

Reference -

[`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function

[`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function

---

As [Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan) pointed out, you can also chain jQuery methods. For instance you could do this:

```
$('#fload').empty().load(toLoad);
```

which will empty and load all in one swoop.